# Hide Chrome Show password button

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to remove the Show password button in Chrome?

If there is no official way, is there a hack like in Firefox?

Comment: There's a quick fix available here: <https://kickass.to/google-chrome-disable-show-password-button-t8127435.html>

Comment: page not found 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official or hack way, afaik. An alternative is to clone [Chromium's source code](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/checkout) & set the boolean `showPasswords` in [this line](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/resources/options/password_manager_list.js&exact_package=chromium&q=list-inline-button%20custom-appearance&l=66) to false to hide the 'Show Password' option.